# Método getView() não é chamado no Array Adapter

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

Estou desenvolvendo um app android e estou enfrentando o seguinte problema, criei um Adapter para preencher meu ListView porem preenche somente o cabeçalho e não estar entrando no método getView() para preencher os itens da minha lista, segue abaixo o código.

**XML onde contém o ListView**

```
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/linear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context="br.com.gerenciarsc.nfce.view.PagamentoActivity">

            <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_adicionarpgto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:onClick="adicionaPagamento"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/btnaddpagto"
                bootstrap:bootstrapBrand="success"
                bootstrap:bootstrapSize="lg"
                bootstrap:roundedCorners="true" />

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dip" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/list_view_pagamento"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </TableLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Código do Botão onde chamo o Adapter que deveria preencher meu listview**

```
final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_pagamento, listView, false);
        listView.addHeaderView(rowView);
        if (listaPagamentos.size() > 0 && listaPagamentos != null)
            listView.setAdapter(new ListaArrayPagamento(this, R.layout.list_item_pagamento, listaPagamentos, pgtoRepo));
```

**Minha classe Adapter**

```
public class ListaArrayPagamento extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List lista;
    private PagamentoRepositorio pgtoRepo;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ListaArrayPagamento(Context context, int recurso, List objetos, PagamentoRepositorio pgtoRepo) {
        super(context, recurso, objetos);

        this.pgtoRepo = pgtoRepo;
        this.lista = objetos;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //position = position - 1;
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_pagamento, parent, false);

        if (lista.get(position).getClass().isInstance(new PagamentoVenda())) {
            final PagamentoVenda pagamentoVenda = (PagamentoVenda) lista.get(position);
            try {
                pgtoRepo.Atualizar(pagamentoVenda);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_formapgto)).setText(pagamentoVenda.formaPagamento);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_valor)).setText(String.valueOf(pagamentoVenda.valorParcela));
            if (pagamentoVenda.dtVencimento != null)
                ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_dtvencimento)).setText(MainActivity.converteDataParaString(pagamentoVenda.dtVencimento, getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.data_formato)));
            else
                ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_dtvencimento)).setText("À vista");
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tem certeza de que tem itens no seu `listaPagamentos`?

Comment: Sim Androiderson, eu debuguei o código e no listaPagamentos.size() ta 2, criei o método 'código'  @Override
public int getCount() {
    return lista.size();
} e entra nele e me retorna 2 mas não entra no getview()

Comment: Várias coisas estranhas no seu código: o *layout list_item_pagamento* é usado tanto no header como nos itens, o *Adapter* é do tipo `ArrayAdapter<String>` mas você passa um `List` sem indicação do tipo, o porquê de usar *PagamentoRepositorio* no *Adapter* assim como este teste `if (lista.get(position).getClass().isInstance(new PagamentoVenda()))`

Comment: Mas o problema está e que nem entra no getView() entao nem chega nessa parte do código.

Comment: Eu, particularmente, nunca tentar colocar uma listview dentro de um scrollview, talvez seu problema comece por ai

Comment: Obrigado @franM, retirei o scrollview do meu layou e funcionou corretamente agora, coloque este comentário como resposta para ser marcado como resposta e você ganhar reputação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu, particularmente, nunca tentar colocar uma listview dentro de um scrollview, talvez seu problema comece por ai

Answer (score 0):

Amigo eu faria assim por alto.

1 Extenda baseAdapter no lugar de arrayAdapter
2 Passe sua lista de objetos/strings como parametro.
3 inflaria seu layout do listView no getView()
4 listView.setAdapter(new seuApadter(suaListaObjetos(), context));